# SceneKit - Textures not properly displayed

Tags: ios, swift, textures, offset, scenekit

I have a cube (rounded) and want to display a texture on one of it's side. I can access the material on that side with:

```
var tex1: SCNMaterial! = cube.geometry?.materialWithName("_1")!
```

I then set it's image contents:

```
tex1.diffuse.contents = "cube1"
```

This then looks like this:

[image: cube with texture]

This shows me that it does work, but the white part is not in the center as 
it should be. (The image I am using has the white part in the center.)

I tried to use offset to move the image around on the surface, I would like scale it as well. I tried it like this:

```
tex1.diffuse.contents.offset = SCNVector3Make(20, 0, 0)
```

That gives me errors: it says it cannot assign the result of that expression. (I also tried `contentMode`, same error, I think because these are for UI, not SCN)

**Questions**

1. Does anyone know what I can do?
2. Maybe offset is not the way to go?
3. How can I scale the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of a material property's `contents` is `AnyObject`, which means the compiler will allow you to call any method (defined on any object type) on it. That doesn't mean all methods or property accessors are actually really implemented by the actual class that's in your particular `contents`.

Material properties do have a [`contentsTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterialProperty/contentsTransform) option, though. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you provide me with a little more information please? I figured to scale with `myMat.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)` and also translated with `myMat.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -0.05, 0)`. But when I do the translation it removes the scaling. Any idea? The weird thing is that my images I use are squared and so I thought it will just fit automatically.

Comment: `MakeScale` gives you a transformation matrix. `MakeTranslation` also gives you a transformation matrix. [How do you combine transformations?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) Hint: there's an `SCNMatrix4` function or two that takes a pair of matrices and returns a new one.

Comment: here is my solution : 
myMat.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.5), SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -0.05, 0))
it's working very well

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution :
create offset:

```
let offsetVal =  SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -0.05, 0)
```

create scale:

```
let scaleVal = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
```

if you want to set Offset Property  only:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = offsetVal
```

if you want to set Scale Property only:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = scaleVal
```

if you want to mix them:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(scaleVal, offsetVal)
```

hope this helpful!!!